# std::move and construction/destruction of objects

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, move-semantics

As I remember, before any call of function, it allocs memory for function result and parameters at stack. 
Does that means if I have

```
T func()
{
    T a;
    return std::move(a);
}
```

I will still have copying, because it already was allocated memory for entire T?
I also read at similar questions that

```
return a;
```

is same as

```
return std::move(a);
```

So, I can't avoid copying to stack? Is rvalue a value at stack?

Will it be good way to use it somewhere:

```
T a = std::move(func());
```

So I will avoid copying result of function? Do I still have to create special move constructor and move operator=?

I tried to test it and got:

```
class Temp
{
public:
    Temp()
    {
        cout << "construct" << endl;
        i = 5;
    }
    ~Temp()
    {
        cout << "destruct" << endl;
    }
    Temp(const Temp& t)
    {
        i = t.i;
        cout << "copy construct" << endl;
    }
    Temp operator=(const Temp& t)
    {
        i = t.i;
        cout << "operator =" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    int i;

};

Temp tempfunc1()
{
    Temp t1;
    t1.i = 7;
    return t1;
}

Temp tempfunc2()
{
    Temp t1;
    t1.i = 8;
    return std::move(t1);
}

int main()
{
        Temp t1;
        Temp t2;
        t2.i = 6;
        t1 = t2;
        cout << t1.i << endl;
        t1.i = 5;
        t1 = std::move(t2);
        cout << t1.i << endl;
        cout << "NEXT" << endl;
        t1 = tempfunc1();
        cout << t1.i << endl;
        cout << "NEXT" << endl;
        t1 = std::move(tempfunc1());
        cout << t1.i << endl;
        cout << "NEXT" << endl;
        t1 = tempfunc2();
        cout << t1.i << endl;
        cout << "NEXT" << endl;
        t1 = std::move(tempfunc2());
        cout << t1.i << endl;
}
```

with result:

```
construct
construct
operator =
copy construct
destruct
6
operator =
copy construct
destruct
6
NEXT
construct
copy construct
destruct
operator =
copy construct
destruct
destruct
7
NEXT
construct
copy construct
destruct
operator =
copy construct
destruct
destruct
7
NEXT
construct
copy construct
destruct
operator =
copy construct
destruct
destruct
8
NEXT
construct
copy construct
destruct
operator =
copy construct
destruct
destruct
8
```

As if there is nothing from using std::move. Or it works **just** if there exist speacial constructor and destructor?

Why "t1 = t2" calls both copy constructor and operator=?

Excuse me for such big heap of questions that may be very simple, even after reading much about that, maybe because my bad english, I still need explanations.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "Why "t1 = t2" calls both copy constructor and operator=?" Because first you call `operator=` to get the object to copy, then you copy construct.

Comment: @Theolodis It's a normal assignment. The problem is that the copy assignment operator returns a copy, instead of a reference.

Comment: @Theolodis So it firstly builds at stack returned value and then copy that builded at stack value to it's destination? So, copying goes throw third object at stack?

Comment: @DDrmmr, I specially used it without references, because with them there there will no need in moving objects.

Comment: You never gave your class any constructors or assignment operators that take a `Temp &&`, so of course the `Temp const&` versions would always be called. And your `operator=` returns a `Temp` (by value), so of course there would be a constructor call to create that return value. You should probably reduce the scope of your question, as it is, there are quite a large number of questions here.

Comment: So, there is no magic at std::move and move semantic, I just got instruments from compiler to not create, for example, my own function calling it "move function" as earlier, but now I have special constructor for that and function (std::move) to call it?

std::move don't work if I didn't wrote special Test&& constructor?

Comment: @Arkady All `std::move` does is make an lvalue look like an rvalue (this should give you a hint that there is no need to use it in your examples). So you need an rvalue-ref overload if you want special rvalue-ref behaviour.

Comment: @juanchopanza earlier if I need to "move" something, I had to alloc memory (using "new", for example), and then copy pointer. And I thought std::move was created to avoid using manually memory allocation for those tasks: I can create "T t1;" and then "move" it to "t2", as pointers copying, but avoiding pointers. And I thought it was implemented on compiler level, not asking programmer manually create such moving (as copy operator and copy constructors was automated). It is pitty I'm wrong.

Comment: @Arkady: If you follow the [rule of zero](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2012/08/15/rule-of-zero.html), then such move constructors will be manually created for you. The problem is that in your example, you have manually specified `const &` versions, which disallows the compiler from creating `&&` versions (because automatically creating such versions would be unsafe and create backwards compatibility issues in some situations).

Comment: @Mankarse: I think you mean that "... move constructors will be *automatically* created for you"

Comment: @Edward: Indeed I did. Too late to edit now I guess...

Comment: `return a` is actually better than `return std::move(a)` because the latter prevents RVO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made some changes to your code which may help you understand and explore how this all works.  I added an `id` element to each `Temp` object to make it easier to understand which object is which and also changed the signature of the `operator=` to return a reference rather than an object.  First, here is the required `include` to make it into a complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

Next, here's the class which now includes a `std::move` constructor (with the `&&`) and a move = operator:

```
class Temp
{
    int id;
public:
    Temp() : id(++serial), i(5)
    {
        cout << "construct " << id << endl;
    }
    ~Temp()
    {
        cout << "destruct " << id << endl;
    }
    Temp(const Temp& t) : id(++serial), i(t.i)
    {
        cout << "copy construct " << id << " from " << t.id << endl;
    }
    Temp(Temp &&t) : id(++serial), i(t.i)
    {
        t.i = 5;  // set source to a default state
        cout << "move construct " << id << " from " << t.id << endl;
    }
    Temp &operator=(const Temp& t)
    {
        i = t.i;
        cout << "operator = " << id << " from " << t.id << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    Temp &operator=(Temp&& t)
    {
        i = t.i;
        t.i = 5;  // set source to a default state
        cout << "move operator = " << id << " from " << t.id << endl;
        return *this;
    }
    int i;
    static int serial;
};


int Temp::serial = 0;
```

Your functions are still the same, but see the comment

```
Temp tempfunc1()
{
    Temp t1;
    t1.i = 7;
    return t1;
}

Temp tempfunc2()
{
    Temp t1;
    t1.i = 8;
    return std::move(t1);   // not necessary to call std::move here
}
```

I've slightly altered `main()` to show how this all works:

```
int main()
{
    Temp t1;   
    Temp t2;   
    t2.i = 6;   
    t1 = t2;   
    cout << t1.i << endl;
    t1.i = 5;
    t1 = t2;
    cout << t1.i << endl;
    cout << "NEXT" << endl;
    t1 = tempfunc1();
    cout << t1.i << endl;
    cout << "NEXT" << endl;
    t1 = std::move(tempfunc1());
    cout << t1.i << endl;
    cout << "NEXT" << endl;
    t1 = tempfunc2();
    cout << t1.i << endl;
    cout << "NEXT" << endl;
    Temp t3(tempfunc1());
    cout << t3.i << endl;
    cout << "NEXT" << endl;
    Temp t4(t1);
    cout << t4.i << endl;
}
```

Finally here is the output:

```
construct 1
construct 2
operator = 1 from 2
6
operator = 1 from 2
6
NEXT
construct 3
move operator = 1 from 3
destruct 3
7
NEXT
construct 4
move operator = 1 from 4
destruct 4
7
NEXT
construct 5
move construct 6 from 5
destruct 5
move operator = 1 from 6
destruct 6
8
NEXT
construct 7
7
NEXT
copy construct 8 from 1
8
destruct 8
destruct 7
destruct 2
destruct 1
```

As you can see, with the fixed `operator=`, no temporary is created.  Also once the move version of `operator=` is provided, temporary objects (as with those returned by your `tempfunc1()` and `tempfunc2()` functions) automatically use move semantics.  Your `tempfunc2()` doesn't really need the `std::move` call within it.  As you can see, that merely creates yet another temporary, so it hurts more than it helps.  Finally note the in the creation of `t3` that there is only a single object created and no temporary or `move` constructor is required.

### update

It's probably worth noting that a move constructor doesn't really help much in this trivial class, but it can help a lot for classes that use allocated memory or are computationally expensive to create.  In those cases, it's useful to remember that there are multiple steps required in a move constructor (or in the move version of `operator=`).  Specifically, you must:

1. release any resources used by the destination object, then
2. move the resources from the source object to the destination object, then
3. set the source object state such that the destructor may be called (for example, if the class had memory allocated, you should set the pointer to `nullptr` so that the destructor will operate correctly) and then finally,
4. return `*this`.

Comment: t1 = std::move(tempfunc1()); and t1 = tempfunc1(); (at 3 and 4th objects)
Both gave same move semantic! Why simple t1 = tempfunc1() called move operator?

Comment: @Arkady: because the compiler "knows" that the temporary is about to be deleted anyway, it uses the move version of `operator =` as an easy optimization.